# Algorithm for updating start dates of cycles based on entry

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

This is what happens: users can log various entries each day. one of these entries (lets say x) marks the start of a cycle **if** last x entry was more than 5 days ago. In other words, each cycle starts when an x entry is logged and it's been more than 5 days since the last entry.

Cycle start dates are stored in a table. Whenever an x entry is logged, these would have to be checked and updated, since the new entry can be in one of the past days, falling between two other x entries and changing the cycle start dates.

I want to find the most efficient way to do this.

Right now what I have in mind is this:

```
1.get x entry (current_x) find the last x entry before this. (last_x)

2.find what cycle last_x falls to (Cycle2) 

3.A. if current_x - last_x >5: mark current_x as cycle3's start date 

3.B. else: make no change to start dates (meaning current_x is part of Cycle2)

4.find first x entry after current_x (first_x_after) 

5.A. if first_x_after - current_x >5: mark first_x_after for Cycle4's start date, 
then go check the x after first_x_after  

5.B. else: finish
```

What I want to know is:

1. Is this efficient?
2. Do you see any situation I'm not covering?
3. Would this be a good idea if I had to hit a database for editing the cycle dates?

Comment: So you already have all the logs and want to create the table for the cycle starts (otherwise I wouldn't see any need for step 4. and 5.)? Why isn't it sufficient to just put all logged entries in a table (timestamp, user)? You could get cycle starts easily with a query.

Comment: @maraca users would be logging all the time, so cycle starts are potentially always changing. Could I get start dates with a query if thats a case? Like a query that would only give me x entries that have 5 day difference with the one before them?

Comment: Yes you could, e.g. `select * from mytable a where not exists (select 1 from mytable b where a.user = b.user and datediff(b.datetime, a.datetime) between 0 and 5`. Cycle starts are not always changing, a logging event could only start a new cycle but doesn't affect the existing cycle starts.